# s.substr is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvg

I am using [canvg](https://github.com/canvg/canvg), but when I run this:

```
jQuery("#print").on("click", function() {
    mySvg();
});

function mySvg() {
    var svg = jQuery("#map svg");
  canvg(document.getElementById('canvas'), svg);
}
```

I get this in console

> canvg.js:58 Uncaught TypeError: s.substr is not a function

Here it is [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6r2jug6o/339/)

Comment: The second argument to `canvg` is annotated as follows in the source: `s: svg string, url to svg file, or xml document`. You're passing in a jQuery object.

Answer (score 3):

Siguza is correct, you want to get the inner HTML of your SVG so (assuming `#map` is the direct parent of your target `svg`):

```
var svg = jQuery('#map');
var txt = svg.innerHTML;
```

Then you want to pass the `txt` variable as your second `canvg()` argument.